# Excel macro to compare sql queries excluding parameters?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, parameters, qsqlquery

I have two sheets with sql queries with parameters passed to it.except for the parameters all of the queries generated are same.How to build a excel macro to compare sql queries excluding parameters in both the sheets?

Comment: It would help your question to show two examples of the type of text you want to compare, and what you want the result of the comparison to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manasi, if you have just two sheets, and if you will not be in need of repeating this comparison, `Microsoft Word` can help you.

Copy your sheet1 in a word file & save it.  Then copy your second sheet in another word file & save it.  Then select `compare` command in `review` tab of the word and select your files.  Word will show you the differences in letter level (Make sure `all markup` selected in word's `tracking` command group in tab `review`.